# Can the CycloneDX for NPM docker image be used to generate SBOMs for projects that do not support Node v12?

Tags: node.js, npm

CycloneDX for NPM states that it requires Node version 12.  If I have an older project (for example an Angular 7 project) that only supports Node version 10.  Can I run CycloneDX for NPM on the commandline as a docker container to generate an SBOM?  Or must the project also support Node v12?

I have run the command against an older project and it seems to work, however I'm concerned that the generated SBOM might be incomplete or inaccurate due to the Node version.  Updating the application to a newer version of Angular is possible as a long-term solution, however
short-term I was wondering simply running the app in a container will work.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the CycloneDX tool for Node.js standalone like that:

```
    npm install --global @cyclonedx/cyclonedx-npm
    cyclonedx-npm --output-file sbom.json --ignore-npm-errors package.json
```

The npm and Node.js version in your search path must satisfy the system requirements for the CycloneDX tool in this case. But it will not interfere with your project settings and your project does not need to run with Node.js 12 or newer.